# tarea en DevC++

Tags: dev-c++

me pidieron hacer esta tarea en DevC++, pero no me arroja el resultado. ya le puse un contador y nada, tenia un acumulador para cada rango, pero se lo quite porque igual no me arrojaba el resultado.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{



    int i,edad,n=0,j=0,a=0,v=0;
    float peso,pe_n=0,pe_j=0,pe_a=0,pe_v=0,pro_n,pro_j,pro_a,pro_v;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        printf ("persona %d \n",i);
        printf("Introduce tu edad  ");
        scanf("%d",&edad);
        printf("Introduce tu peso  ");
        scanf("%f",&peso);
        if(n>0 && n<=12)
        pe_n=pe_n+peso;
        else 
        if(j>13 && j<=29)
        pe_j=pe_j+peso;
        else
        if (a>30 && a<=59)
        pe_a=pe_a+peso;
        else 
        if(v>=60)
        pe_v=pe_v+peso;
    
            
        
    }
    
    

        
        
        
        printf ("El promedio de peso de los niños es  %.2f \n",pro_n);
        printf ("El promedio de peso de los jovenes es  %.2f \n",pro_j);
        printf ("El promedio de peso de los adultos es  %.2f \n",pro_a);
        printf ("El promedio de peso de los viejos es  %.2f \n",pro_v);
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes. El código no debería estar en imágenes, recuerda que no todos podemos verlo... por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/559476/edit) tu pregunta y pon el código en su respectivo formato.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Las llaves del `int main()` no se están cerrando, por la cual los `printf` no te va a funcionar (ni nada de la lógica).

También veo que estás usando muchas variables innecesarias. Tu código sería así:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int i,edad;
    float peso,pe_n=0,pe_j=0,pe_a=0,pe_v=0;
    
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        printf ("persona %d \n",i);
        printf("Introduce tu edad: ");
        scanf("%d",&edad);
        printf("Introduce tu peso: ");
        scanf("%f",&peso);
        if(edad>0 && edad<=12)
        pe_n=pe_n+peso;
        else 
        if(edad>13 && edad<=29)
        pe_j=pe_j+peso;
        else
        if (edad>30 && edad<=59)
        pe_a=pe_a+peso;
        else 
        if(edad>=60)
        pe_v=pe_v+peso;
    }
    printf ("El promedio de peso de los niños es: %.2f \n",pe_n);
    printf ("El promedio de peso de los jóvenes es: %.2f \n",pe_j);
    printf ("El promedio de peso de los adultos es: %.2f \n",pe_a);
    printf ("El promedio de peso de los viejos es: %.2f \n",pe_v);
}
```

**Output:**

```
// persona 1 
// Introduce tu edad: 14
// Introduce tu peso: 23
// persona 2 
// Introduce tu edad: 14
// Introduce tu peso: 32
// persona 3 
// Introduce tu edad: 14
// Introduce tu peso: 53
// persona 4 
// Introduce tu edad: 50
// Introduce tu peso: 54
// persona 5 
// Introduce tu edad: 45
// Introduce tu peso: 32

// El promedio de peso de los niños es: 0.00 
// El promedio de peso de los jóvenes es: 108.00 
// El promedio de peso de los adultos es: 86.00 
// El promedio de peso de los viejos es: 0.00
```